# javascript - if else not resulting in expected comparision

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new to javascript. I am having a little issue here.
Is javascript `if` / `else` statement different than other languages (c++, java, python)?

Here is the issue that I am having.

- if else statement only accepts `i == 0` and `i == 1` into my new array from myArray.

Why am I not be able to separate other elements into my new array? I used `myArray` for an example. In my real problem, I wouldn't know how many elements I have. That is why I have set up variables `threetimes` and `increaseByThree`. I am just trying to separate name, zip code, and amount into the different array by using a `for` loop.

```js
var nameArray = [], zipCodeArray = [], totalAmountArray = [];
var threeTimes = 3;
var increaseByThree = 0;
var myArray = ["Eric ", "94990", "540", "Sam ", "303030", "350"];

for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  threeTimes += 3;
  increaseByThree += 3;

  if(i == threeTimes || i == 0) {
    nameArray.push(myArray[i]);
  } else if(i == increaseByThree || i == 1) {
    zipCodeArray.push(myArray[i]);
  } else {
    totalAmountArray.push(myArray[i]);
  }
}
console.log(nameArray) 
console.log(zipCodeArray) 
console.log(totalAmountArray)
```

Comment: Hard to understand what you mean here.

Comment: Considering what your `for` loop does, at what other values of `i` would you expect any of these conditions to be true?

Comment: @UnholySheep I tried everything; check the value of i from my for loop, check my variables values. Couldn't figure out why I wasn't able to store elements from old to new arrays.. based on the value of the variable..

Comment: You increase `threeTimes` and `increaseByThree` by 3 on each iteration while `i` only increases by 1 - so I ask again, at which values of `i` do you expect these conditions to be true?

Comment: @UnholySheep i == threeTimes true when i = 0, 3, 6,9,... and i == increaseByThree true when i = 1,4,7,10,13... and so on..

Comment: You might want to print `i`, `threeTimes`, and `increaseByThree` just before the `if` statement to see if they have the values you expect. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @rick If you want to post an answer, post an answer. Don't edit hints into the question.

Comment: @user8515431 I edited your snippet with some logs... if the edit is approved you can runnit and see what @ UnholySheep whas trying to explain you

Comment: Think again: every loop in the `for` increments your variables by 3, and `i` by 1. so first iteration: `i = 0`, `threeTimes=3` and `increaseByThree=3`. next iteration: `i = 1`, `threeTimes=6` and `increaseByThree=6`... so next will be?

Comment: I'd simply log all three variables to the console to see what's happening in each iteration. That should tell you what's amiss with the loop (let alone that simply reading the code should raise a red flag).

Comment: @CalvinNunes Thanks.. I think I am getting an idea now why I wasn't able to do what I wanted to do. let's hope that I will be able to fix this... Thank again CalvinNunes..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your array will be in the format [a0, b0, c0, ....., aN, bN, cN] where N is the number of 'entries' - 1; you could simplify your logic that you determine where to put the value by:

```
const myArray = ["Eric ", "94990", "540", "Sam ", "303030", "350"];
const nameArray = [], zipCodeArray = [], totalAmountArray = [];

for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    switch (i % 3) {
        case 0:
            nameArray.push(myArray[i]);
            break;
        case 1:
            zipCodeArray.push(myArray[i]);
            break;
        case 2:
            totalAmountArray.push(myArray[i]);
            break;
    }
}

console.log(nameArray) 
console.log(zipCodeArray) 
console.log(totalAmountArray)
```

This will work for any size array and cuts out the need for the unnecessary variables and if-else blocks.  Here is a helpful link for javascript's switch block
(https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) which are much cleaner as opposed to if-else blocks and show the  intent more clearly in this case.

Comment: thank you. for your help